# Kendo UI Grid: Unable to create custom grid editor that will add to datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a custom editor to add a multiselect control as an editor.  The data that is in the model for this column is typically a comma separated string.

I can get it to add the tags to the multiselect control and even add user defined tags; however, when I click out of the editor to close it, the values for the multiselect control are not passed to the grid to display in the cell.

```
 function MultiselectReportUserTags(container, options) {
var newitemtext;
var tags = getTags2();
  if(options.model.ReportUserTags != undefined && options.model.ReportUserTags != "" && options.model.ReportUserTags.search(',') > -1 ) { 
      options.model.ReportUserTags = options.model.ReportUserTags.split(','); 
  }
  $("<select multiple='multiple' data-bind='value: ReportUserTags.text' />")
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoMultiSelect({
  select: function (e) {
      debugger;
      var value = e.item.text();
      var dataitems = this.dataSource.data();
      var isNewTag = false;

      if (value.indexOf("Add new tag: ") > -1) {
          isNewTag = true;
      }

      value = value.replace("Add new tag: ", "");

      for (var i = 0; i < dataitems.length; i++) {
          var dataItem = dataitems[i];
          if (dataItem.text == value) {
              this.value().slice(0).push(value);
          }
          else if (dataItem.text.substring(0, "Add new tag: ".length) === "Add new tag: ") {
              if (isNewTag) {

                  this.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
                  this.dataSource.add({ text: value, value: value });
              }
              else {
                  this.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
              }
          }
      }

      this.refresh();
      $

  },
  change: function () {
  },
  dataBound: function () {
      if ((newitemtext || this._prev) && newitemtext != this._prev) {
          newitemtext = this._prev;

          var dataitems = this.dataSource.data();

          var isfound = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < dataitems.length; i++) {
              var dataItem = dataitems[i];

              if (dataItem.value != dataItem.text) {
                  dataItem.text = "Add new tag: " + newitemtext;
                  this.refresh();
                  isfound = true;
              }
          }
          if (!isfound) {
              this.dataSource.add({ text: "Add new tag: " + newitemtext, value: newitemtext });
              this.refresh();
          }
          this.search();
          this.open();
      }
  },
  dataSource: tags,
  dataTextField: "text",
  dataValueField: "value",
  filter: "contains",
  animation: false
  });
}

function getTags2() {

  var tagString = 'POSITION;ASSET;LOT;TRADE';
  var tagArray = tagString.split(";");
  var tags = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tagArray.length; i++) {
      tags[i] = { text: tagArray[i], value: tagArray[i] };
  }

  return tags;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After further research and playing around with the code, I found I could use the Save event on the grid to set the model value to the values from the multiselect editor.